# Sorting Arraylist of Arraylist of Bean

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` of Bean and I need to sort this `ArrayList` according to the `date` variable in Bean.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<DriverLogDatePair>> driverLogList
```

And `DriverLogDatePair` bean have a variable `DateTime date`, it also has a `compareTo` method.

```
public int compareTo(DriverLogDatePair o) {
    return date.compareTo(o.date);
}
```

But I am not able to sort `driverLogList`.

Comment: Which `ArrayList` do you want to sort, the inner or outer one? You have a list of lists and you want to sort on a date element in the inner list, so I assume you want to sort the inner lists - or what?

Comment: How will the ArrayList<DriverLogDatePair> be sorted? You need to provide comparator for that too.

Comment: Do you want to sort all the individual lists? Or do you want to sort the global list (so change the order of the `ArrayList<DriverLogDatePair>`? If second, what criteria you want to use?

Comment: I need to sort the outer one on the basis of the bean date value.

Comment: you need to write your custom `comparator` and use it with the `Collection.sort(list,newcomparator)` method

Comment: That does not make sense unless all beans in the inner list have the same date or you spec an algorithm to determine how a given set of dates are "higher"/"lower" than another set of dates!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to complete this code:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<DriverLogDatePair>> driverLogList = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.sort( driverLogList, new Comparator<ArrayList<DriverLogDatePair>>(){
   @Override public int compare(
      ArrayList<DriverLogDatePair> left,
      ArrayList<DriverLogDatePair> right )
   {
      return 0;
   }});
```

Because the first array contains an array which contains a Comparable.
The comparator you provide is for DriverLogDatePair not for ArrayList< DriverLogDatePair >

(... After comments of this post... )

At your request, to complete the comparator I suggest:

```
int size = left.size();
int diff = size - right.size();
if( diff != 0 ) return diff;
for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
   diff = left.get( i ).compareTo( right.get(i) );
   if( diff != 0 ) return diff;
}
```

But I have no idea of the true meaning of this comparison.
It's a semantic problem, is this really what you want?

Comment: Aubin can you please tell me what I need to put inside this. I mean how will I compare inside this.

Comment: Aubin I used you code and added for(int i=0;i<left.size();){
        return left.get(i).getDate().compareTo(right.get(i).getDate());      
       } and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you sort `driverLogList` it tries to compare the contained `ArrayList` objects. I would write a wrapper for that list:

```
public class DriverLogDatePairList extends ArrayList<DriverLogDatePair> implements Comparable<DriverLogDatePairList> {

    public int compareTo(DriverLogDatePairList o) {
        //your comparison criteria
    }
}
```

Then you can use it this way and sort it:

```
ArrayList<DriverLogDatePairList> driverLogList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can sort `List`s using

```
Collections.sort( list , comparator )
```

So, assuming you want to sort the inner lists, iterate through the outer list and use that construct to sort the elements, after having implemented a fitting comparator:

```
Comparator comparator = 
    new Comparator<DateTime>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare( DateTime o1, DateTime o2 )
        {
            return o1.compareTo( o2 );
        }
    }
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Your compare method is seems wrong to me..

it should be like:
(here i am assuming date as DriverLogDatePair Object )

```
public int compareTo(DriverLogDatePair o) {
    if(date.date < o.date) return -1;
    else if (date.date < o.date) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```