# Sorting ArrayList of Arraylist<String> in java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator, comparable

I have an ArrayList of ArrayList of String.

In Outer ArrayList on each index each Inner ArrayList has four items have four parameters.

1. Contacts Id
2. Contacts Name
3. Contacts Adress
4. Contacts Number

Now I want to sort the complete ArrayList of the on the basis of Contact Name Parameter.

Means I want to access the outer Arraylist and the inner ArrayList present on each index of outer Arraylist should be sorted according to contact Name.

Comparator / Comparable Interfaces not likely to help me.

Collection.sort can't help me

[Sorting Arraylist of Arraylist of Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154108/sorting-arraylist-of-arraylist-of-bean). I have read this post but it is for `ArrayList` of `ArrayList<Object>`. How to figure out this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by four parameters to an ArrayList?

Comment: If your inner array list is expected to always have four elements that are well defined make that a class with fields for `Contacts Id, Name, Address and Number` and have an `ArrayList` of that class.

Comment: @jlordo - No, he has a list of lists, not 4 separate lists.

Comment: @StephenC: Yes, I know that he has a list of lists. I just wasn't sure if there was one list per contact, or 4 inner lists, where each contact's information is stored on the same index in each of those 4 lists ;) OP could have cleared that by showing how he populates that list of lists.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming your Lists in your List has Strings in the order id, name, address and number (i.e. name is at index 1), you can use a `Comparator`, as follows:

```
List<List<String>> list;
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<List<String>> () {
    @Override
    public int compare(List<String> a, List<String> b) {
        return a.get(1).compareTo(b.get(1));
    }
});
```

Incidentally, it matters not that you are using `ArrayList`: It is good programming practice to declare variables using the abstract type, i.e. `List` (as I have in this code).

Answer (score 4):

I feel bad posting this, because `List<Contact>` would be the **much better** choice. Something like this would be possible, though:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> yourList = ...
Collections.sort(yourList, new Comparator<ArrayList<String>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ArrayList<String> one, ArrayList<String> two) {
        return one.get(1).compareTo(two.get(1));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  import java.util.Collections;
  import java.util.Comparator;
  import java.util.List;


  public class ListsUtils {

      public static void sortListOfLists(List < List < String >> listOfLists) {

          // first sort the inner arrays using collections.sort
          for (List < String > innerList: listOfLists) {
              Collections.sort(innerList);
          }

          // now sort by comparing the first string of each inner list using a comparator
          Collections.sort(listOfLists, new ListOfStringsComparator());
      }

      static final class ListOfStringsComparator implements Comparator < List < String >> {

          @
          Override
          public int compare(List < String > o1, List < String > o2) {
              // do other error checks here as well... such as null. outofbounds, etc
              return o1.get(0).compareTo(o2.get(0));
          }

      }
  }
```

I guess I just assumed you had to sort a list of string arrays... thats why I sorted the list of inner arrays first, then sorted the outer list by comparing the 1st item of each array.  Didnt read the contacts you had in your answer.

In that case remove the for loop for sorting the inner list and you should still be able to sort using the comparator, but compare to the right index instead of the 1st element.

Collections.sort(listOfLists, new ListOfStringListComparator());

Answer (score 1):

> Comparator / Comparable Interfaces can't help because I don't have any objects.

Incorrect.  You do have objects.  All of the things you are trying to sort are objects.

If you are trying to sort the `ArrayList<String>` objects in an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`, you need to implement a `Comparator<ArrayList<String>>`.  (The Comparable approach is the wrong one for this data structure.  You would need to declare a custom subclass of ArrayList ... and that's yuck!)

---

But a better idea would be to represent your objects with custom classes.  In this case, your `ArrayList of String` should be a custom `Contact` class with 4 fields, getters and (if required) setters.  Then you declare that as implementing `Comparable<Contact>`, and implement the `compareTo` method.

---

Other Answers show how to implement a Comparator based on just one field of the list.  That may be sufficient, but it will give you a sort order where the order of a pair of different "John Smith"s would be indeterminate.  (I would use a second field as a tie-breaker.  The Id field would be ideal if the ids are unique.)

Comment: Comparator<ArrayList<String>> Con you provide me an example.

Comment: See Arjun Rao's answer for a simple example that sorts on just one of the fields ...

Comment: @spehen C I am correcting my statement.Comparator / Comparable Interfaces can't help because I don't have any objects.Thanks for making me aware.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a class for your data structure (if you can't, then specify why. I can't see any good reason not to):

```
public class Contact implements Comparable {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String number;

    // Getters and setters, and compareTo.
}
```

Then use that in your list instead:

```
List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
```

Sorting it will then be trivial.

Comment: I have given the responsibility of sorting. I can't change my seniors code.

Comment: Then give your seniors a kick in their butt! Show them you know better, and do it properly ;)

Comment: you are true Nilsh. But for now please me some solution.

Comment: The solution is to visit your local shoe shop and buy some heavy-duty butt-kicking boots :-)

Comment: There are lot's of other answers to your question here, if you're looking for a solution that does not involve improving the code quality.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following Comparator:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<ArrayList<String>> {
    private static int indexToCompare = 1;
    @Override
    public int compare(ArrayList<String> o1, ArrayList<String> o2) {
        return o1.get(indexToCompare).compareTo(o2.get(indexToCompare));
    }

}
```

Here `indexToCompare` is the index of the arraylist which corresponds to Contact Name. In your case "1"

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case of not treating collections as first-class objects. Have a new class called "Contact" instead of abstracting it as an ArrayList, and use the Comparator.